# How to stop content getting centered in react-full page?

Tags: css, reactjs, tailwind-css, fullpage.js

I'm using react full page scroll for the scrolling effect but with it by default all the content getting centered

Does anyone know how to stop my content from getting center?

Github link: https://github.com/alvarotrigo/react-fullpage

Comment: remove classNames from components and add ur own

Comment: that section class?

Comment: Slider scroll is getting render against the section class 

If I remove it then my slide data didn't get render

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pass the props `verticalCentered={false}` on the fullpage.js initialisation.

Comment: Thanks!
I see it before but in rush I forget about it.